# How to save a new entity that refers existing entity in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Imagine the following models:

Employee:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "employee_project", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Emp_Id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Proj_id"))
private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<Project>();
```

Project:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
```

Now if I create a new employee that refers to an existing project and try to persist that employee, I get an error:

```
detached entity passed to persist: Project
```

I create the employee as follows:

```
public void createNewEmployee(EmployeeDTO empDTO) {

  Employee emp = new Employee();
  // add stuff from DTO, including projects

  repository.saveAndFlush(emp);  // FAILS
}
```

and I update existing ones like this:

```
public void updateEmployee(EmployeeDTO empDTO) {

   Employee emp = repository.findOne(empDTO.getId());
   // set stuff from DTO, including projects

   repository.saveAndFlush(emp);  // WORKS!
}
```

Answer (score 20):

I guess you're interacting with the repository without expanding the transaction boundaries appropriately. By default, the transaction (and thus session) boundary is at the repository method level. This causes the `Project` instance to be detached from the `EntityManager`, so that it cannot be included in a persist operation.

The solution here is to extend the transaction boundary to the client:

```
@Component
class YourRepositoryClient {

  private final ProjectRepository projects;
  private final EmployeeRepository employees;

  // … constructor for autowiring

  @Transactional
  public void doSomething() {
    Project project = projects.findOne(1L);
    Employee employee = employees.save(new Employee(project));
  }
}
```

This approach causes the `Project` instance stay a managed entity and thus the persist operation to be executed for the fresh `Employee` instance being handled correctly.

The difference with the two repository interactions is that in the second case you'll have a detached instance (has already been persisted, has an id set), where as in the first example you have a completely unmanaged instances that does not have an id set. The id property is what causes the repository to differentiate between calling `persist(…)` and `merge(…)`. So the first approach will cause a `persist(…)` to be triggered, the second will cause a `merge(…)`.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I'd still like to know why my update method works without fetching the projects from their repository (see my updated question for details)

Comment: It's not a good idea to extend questions here as they invalidate the answer to some degree. Better ask new questions. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is that spring's `@Transactional` or JPA's, or does it matter?

Comment: Spring's. There's no `@Transactional` in JPA. Generally speaking, use whatever transaction control mechanism you like (e.g. Spring annotations, EJB transaction annotations, JTA 1.2's `@Transactional`).

Comment: How to do it without preflight `findOne`? I mean to force Spring Data to detect that child object already exists in the database (by given `id`) and should be just `merge`-it (automatically, by Spring Data, not by me!!!) ??? Is Spring Data sucks in such convenience?